# jquery one div replacing another

Tags: jquery, html

Say i have this html file with several divs and several buttons(or links).

i don't want to more than one div to ever appear simultaneously. I want to, once you click a button/link, any div displayed disappears and its corresponding div replaces it on screen.

```
<button onclick="toggleByClass('1');">Toggle 1</button>
<button onclick="toggleByClass('2');">Toggle 2</button>
<button onclick="toggleByClass('3');">Toggle 3</button>

<div class="1">content1</div>
<div class="2">content2</div>
<div class="3">content3</div>
```

Up to now i only managed to toggle the divs, but that allows more than one to appear simultaneously.

Comment: show what is `toggleByClass('1')`

Comment: show the code for the functions

Comment: the rest of the code isn't really relevant is it?
an html file with just this code i provided will toggle the divs. only it will allow them to appear simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried in Jquery. It might help you

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.content_div').hide();
    $(document).on('click','.toggle_btn',function()
    {
        $('.content_div').hide();
        var div_to_show = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.'+div_to_show ).slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="toggle_btn" id="1">Toggle 1</button>
    <button class="toggle_btn" id="2">Toggle 2</button>
    <button class="toggle_btn" id="3">Toggle 3</button>

    <div class="1 content_div">content1</div>
    <div class="2 content_div">content2</div>
    <div class="3 content_div">content3</div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### jQuery

U could use jQuery's `toggle()` function, or just call the `show() / hide()` functions if you just want to show/hide the divs, if they are already in your html, as in your example.

Just remember to `hide()` all the divs before calling `show()` on the new one, to make only one visible at a time.

#### Css class

Another approach you could use, is to define a `.hidden` class in your css, and append that to the classList whenever you want to hide that div.

```
.hidden { visible: none; }
```

But then you might need to query for the div's using ID instead of by class, as that might cause a problem when changing the class-attribute dynamically. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could clean it up a little, starting from HTML:

```
<button >Toggle 1</button>
<button >Toggle 2</button>
<button >Toggle 3</button>

<div class="div">content1</div>
<div class="div">content2</div>
<div class="div">content3</div>
```

Point of the class is to be reusable, so, give all elements same class...

To hide all divs at the start, if you want, do it by CSS:

```
.div {
  display:none;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
$('.div').hide();
$('.div').eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

I've used these fine built-in jQuery functions:

https://api.jquery.com/index/

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

There are more ways, of course (by using data attributes, etc, etc...)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zL24hkur/